# Is there a way to maximize this probability by taking the derivative of the cumulative normal distribution function?

Tags: probability, self-learning, brownian-motion

I'm self-studying Brownian motion and encountered the following problem.

[image]

I understand the author's solution, and it is clear why maximizing the right-hand side of the inequality provides such $t$ that maximizes $A(t) < -1$.

My question is, if we want to maximize $$N\left(\frac{-1 - 0.4t}{\sqrt{0.36}t}\right),$$ could we not set

$$N'\left(\frac{-1 - 0.4t}{\sqrt{0.36}t}\right) = 0,$$

giving us $$\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} = 0,$$

where $x = \frac{-1 - 0.4t}{\sqrt{0.36}t}$ ?

However, trying to solve for $t$ would appear to be taking the natural log of 0, which is impossible.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Shouldn't your derivative have a $dx/dt$ term?

Comment: Your expression in brackets slips from $\dfrac{-1 - 0.4t}{\sqrt{0.36 t }}$ to $\dfrac{-1 - 0.4t}{\sqrt{0.36}t}$

Comment: If you are trying to maximise $\Phi\left(\dfrac{-1 - 0.4t}{\sqrt{0.36t}}\right)$, you might note that $\Phi$, the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal, is an increasing function, so you could just maximise $\dfrac{-1 - 0.4t}{\sqrt{0.36t}}$.  Even if you do not take this shortcut, you would still need to use the chain rule including $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, as @wythagoras has said, and this would have the same effect